# Adding reference to a table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Please how can I reference a table when not using the default table id as the table's primary key? I created two tables one having email as the primary key and I want to have this table email as the foreign key in the other table. Please How can i achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may create table with email as primary key like this:

```
create_table :users, id: false do |t|
  t.string :email, primary_key: true
  t.string :name

  t.timestamps
end

create_table :posts do |t|
  t.string :title
  t.text :body
  t.string :user_email

  t.timestamps
end
```

And define your models like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.primary_key = 'email'
  has_many :posts, foreign_key: :user_email
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user, foreign_key: :user_email
end
```

That's all you need to do. Also you may keep id as primary key for `User` model but use use `email` as foreign key - this may be easier way to handle your models.